# Where are 75 and 34?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

$$32 \supset 108 + 110$$
$$98 \supset 97 + 116$$
$$71 \supset 31$$
$$98 < 117 < 38 < (31 = 87) < 32 < 84 < (105 \approx 115) < 49 < 113$$
$$(39 = 65 = 68 = 70 \approx 67) \subset 69 \mapsto 90$$
$$95 \supset 98 - 117 + 47$$
$$63 \supset 38 - 115 + 69$$
$$52 \supset 95 + 63 + 49 + 113$$
$$2 < 80 < 52 < (58 \approx 46) < 92 < 93 \le 94$$
$$47 = 78$$
$$\text{75 and 34, where are they?}$$

Bonus question:

$$37 \approx 55 \land 37 \ne 55, \text{why}?$$

I'm sure that someone will find out the solution quickly. Once you figure it out, it becames very easy.

Answer (score 8):

### Partial Answer

I think this puzzle is related to:

> The origin of the name of chemical elements

#### Partial Examples

$(39 = 65 = 68 = 70 \approx 67) \subset 69 \mapsto 90$

> $(\text{Yttrium} = \text{Terbium} = \text{Erbium} = \text{Ytterbium} \approx \text{Holmium}) \subset \text{Thulium} \mapsto \text{Thorium}$
>
>
>  Yttrium, Terbium, Erbium and Ytterbium are named after **[Ytterby Mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ytterby)** in Sweden.
>
>  Holmium is named after **Stockholm**, the capital of Sweden.
>
>  Thulium is named after [Thule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule), a mythical region in **Scandinavia**.
>
>  Thorium is named after Thor, the god in **Norse mythology**.

$2 < 80 < 52 < (58 \approx 46) < 92 < 93 \le 94$

> $\text{Helium} < \text{Mercury} < \text{Tellurium} < (\text{Cerium} \approx \text{Palladium}) < \text{Uranium} < \text{Neptunium} \le \text{Plutonium}$
>
>
>  Helium is named after Helios, the god of the **Sun**.
>
>  Tellurium is named after Tellus, the deity of the **Earth**.
>
>  Cerium is named after **Ceres**, and Palladium is named after **Pallas**. Both are asteroids in the asteroid belt, located between Mars and Jupiter.

The remaining examples, FYI:

> $$\text{Germanium} \supset \text{Hassium} + \text{Darmstadtium}$$
>  $$\text{Californium} \supset \text{Berkelium} + \text{Livermorium}$$
>  $$\text{Lutetium} \supset \text{Gallium}$$
>  $$\text{Californium} < \text{Tennessine} < \text{Strontium} < (\text{Gallium} = \text{Francium}) < \text{Germanium} < \text{Polonium} < (\text{Dubnium} \approx \text{Moscovium}) < \text{Indium} < \text{Nihonium}$$
>  
>  $$\text{Americium} \supset \text{Californium} - \text{Tennessine} + \text{Silver}$$
>  $$\text{Europium} \supset \text{Strontium} - \text{Moscovium} + \text{Thulium}$$
>  $$\text{Tellurium} \supset \text{Americium} + \text{Europium} + \text{Indium} + \text{Nihonium}$$
>  $$\text{Silver} = \text{Platinum}$$

#### Question (Unsolved)

$\text{75 and 34, where are they?}$

> $\text{Rhenium and Selenium, where are they?}$
>
>
>  Rhenium is named after the river Rhine.
>
>  Selenium is named after Selene, the goddess of the Moon.
>
>
>  I couldn't catch any relation between these two :(

#### Bonus Question

$37 \approx 55 \land 37 \ne 55, \text{why}?$

> $\text{Rubidium} \approx \text{Caesium} \land \text{Rubidium} \ne \text{Caesium}, \text{why}?$
>
>
>  Rubidium is named after Latin word *rubidus*, meaning **deep red**.
>
>  Caesium is named after Latin word *caesius*, meaning **sky-blue**.
>
>
>  Both are named after Latin word meaning a color, but they means different color.

Comment: You are very close.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Wow, nice puzzle! Very mysterious at first, but very self-confirming when the solution method is found.